# How to improve ~100 million rows insert + update

Tags: sql-server

**Background**

A customer is collecting prices of different products and wants to update the price in their database if there is any change. We are talking about ~100 million rows of data that comes from scrapping which is stored in spreadsheets.

We are using SQL Server to store this data.

**Issue**

Problem starts when we upload those spreadsheets so the data can be inserted into staging table and updates curated price table.

Following are two steps behind the operation-

> step 1 data is stored in staging table
>
> step 2 price is checked. The ones that changed since last run then
> gets updated in the main curated table "price".

But SQL Server is taking too long

**What I have done so far**

to help step 2 run faster, we created an index on staging table and but that made step 1 slower.

so to help step 1 faster, we disable the index, then bulk insert into the table and then rebuild the said index. which takes about 15 minutes. We don't see any significant improvement.

**What I want help with?**

I am trying to improve performance. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

(This question is "focused" towards performance improvement)

Comment: Please don't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140444/the-price-tables). There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74140444/edit) feature you should be using.

Comment: it was deleted.

Comment: By **you**, not the community, and even if it *was* deleted by the community, that doesn't excuse reposting questions. If a question is closed, then you need to [edit] it to improve it.

Comment: The only person who voted to delete your prior question was [you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF1dF.png). As for downvotes, these aren't rude, they denote that the question isn't useful, helpful, or doesn't demonstrate research; they are a quality rating system. In regards to this question, I would agree with the downvoter: It is not useful to repost a previously closed question.

Comment: I will say, however, that is you are working with a very large number of rows you need to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` then batching is very likely what you are after.

Comment: Why update? Wouldn't it be easier .quicker and cleaner to truncate and load?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using MERGE in your query. It would reduce the I/O operations on the disk drastically. [Here is an example I found on the very first google search of your problem](https://www.vertica.com/blog/use-merge-update-1-million-rows/)

Comment: Also consider bulk collect and bulk insert. There are multiple sources on the internet about your question.

Comment: "It would reduce the I/O operations on the disk drastically" is a rather blanket statement. In a lot of instances it won't help, but it may help if there is careful use of indexing and batching. There is also locking problems to worry about. As always, YMMV and further details are needed to know whether it's the right option.